# Laravel: Strange behaviour of type-hinted class when used twice in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, type-hinting

I encountered a strange behaviour which I do not understand when using type-hinting in a Laravel Controller. I have a Profile controller, which should call the same function of a service twice based on different parameters. However, when I call the function the second time, the result of the first call is changed.

Here is my code; Two users' profiles should be displayed on one page:

```
//use statements are omitted for brevity

class ProfileController extends Controller {

    protected $compose_profile_service;

    public function __construct(ComposeProfileService $compose_profile_service) {
        $this->compose_profile_service = $compose_profile_service;
    }

    public function compare($user1, $user2) {
        $user1_profile = $this->compose_profile_service->composeProfile($user1);
        $user2_profile = $this->compose_profile_service->composeProfile($user2);
        dd($user1_profile); //Problem: This dd() gives me the profile of user2 instead of user1
    }
}

class ComposeProfileService {

    public function composeProfile($user) {
        //Get some stuff from the DB
        $profile_data = $user->profile()->get();
        return $profile_data;
    }
}
```

Of course, if I dd() $user1 or $user2 above the respective call of the compose function, the right user is provided.

Comment: if you `dd($user1_profile)` before calling compose on `$user2` is it the correct profile?

Comment: If you have a service provider that constructs `ComposeProfileService` instances, can you share how it is constructed?

Comment: @Jeff yes! it is the correct one.

Comment: @watcher: as far as I understand, it is constructed using Laravel's IOC container - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container

Comment: @JoschiVzfam if construction of an object requires other objects, then you have to use a service provider to tell the IoC how to make it. I was just asking if you had any weird stuff going on inside of a service provider

Comment: Copied/pasted code. It worked perfectly fine. How exactly are you calling the compare function and where is it fetching the users?